# Mail didn't send when wifi is off and error is not shown

Tags: ios, wifi, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error

NSString *eventResult = nil;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

switch (result) {

    case MFMailComposeResultSent:

            eventResult = @"Mail Sent Succesfully";
            break;

    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:

            eventResult = @"Saved into draft";
            break;
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:

            eventResult = @"Mail Canceled";
            break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:

            NSLog(@"Mail Fail:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            eventResult = @"Mail failed";
            break;
}
    //alert for show status of mail

UIAlertView *mailStatusAlert  = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Email Alert" message:eventResult delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[mailStatusAlert show];
[mailStatusAlert release]
```

I used above code to handle mail status it's working fine when wifi is on but if wifi is off error not shown like faile. But I need that check. Is any other way to handle that error? and can i disable mailcomposeviewcontroller orientation of landscape because my app only support portrait.

Comment: You can use Reachability class to check the internet connection first then send the email.

Comment: ok.what is the use of error in mfmailcomposeviewcontroller?

Comment: *MFMailComposeResultFailed* this is basically related to the mail composition error.

Comment: there is no need to check that error, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller will send that mail to outbox, of mail app in iPhone and will send that mail immediately as soon as internet is available, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: firstly check if internet available then send mail in order to avoid MFMailComposeResultFailed. Now if u happened to sent mail and WIFI got off then no need to worry @Prateek is right in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), in the section **overview**, there are providing explaination on that matter:

> This allows you to generate emails even in situations where the user
>   does **not have network access**, such as in airplane mode. This interface
>   does not provide a way for you to verify whether emails were actually
>   sent.

So there is no need to worry about your internet connection by the time you are generating your email.

As mentioned by ***spider1983*** it is worthy to check your internet connection using the **Reachability** class from Apple or a [third-party](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) (the last one is ARC and GCD compatible)

Answer (score 0):

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

if(controller){

   controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
   [controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
   [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
   [controller release];
}else{
   // your mail address is not configure
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for how an error related to the mail composer can be detected, not how a composer is initialized and called.